# Heroku Node.js app deployment (twit): What am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, heroku

noob here. I've been trying to run the node.js "twit" app on Heroku and it just seems to keep timing out and crashing. I've set it to make a call every 45 seconds, which is way too often, but within the 60second timeout that heroku seems to have, and it still happens

```
> > ←[36m2014-05-24T13:39:36.591605+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting
>     > process with c ommand `node rtd2.js`
>     > ←[36m2014-05-24T13:40:22.733065+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
>     > ←[36m2014-05-24T13:40:22.733072+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m # followers:404
>     > ←[36m2014-05-24T13:40:22.972796+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Favorite:
>     > favorited respon se: 470194277931552800
>     > ←[36m2014-05-24T13:40:22.972789+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
>     > ←[35m2014-05-24T13:40:25.771628+00:00 heroku[run.2775]:←[0m State
>     > changed from s tarting to up ←[35m2014-05-24T13:40:25.727245+00:00
>     > heroku[run.2775]:←[0m Starting process wit h command `node`
>     > ←[35m2014-05-24T13:40:25.692309+00:00 heroku[run.2775]:←[0m Awaiting
>     > client ←[32m2014-05-24T13:40:23.184143+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Starting
>     > process with com mand `node` by username
>     > ←[36m2014-05-24T13:40:38.426516+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed
>     > from star ting to crashed ←[36m2014-05-24T13:40:36.888774+00:00
>     > heroku[web.1]:←[0m Error R10 (Boot timeout ) -> Web process failed to
>     > bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
>     > ←[36m2014-05-24T13:40:36.888952+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Stopping
>     > process with S IGKILL ←[36m2014-05-24T13:40:38.417287+00:00
>     > heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with sta tus 137
>     > ←[35m2014-05-24T13:41:54.765029+00:00 heroku[run.2775]:←[0m Client
>     > connection cl osed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
>     > ←[35m2014-05-24T13:41:56.062749+00:00 heroku[run.2775]:←[0m State
>     > changed from u p to complete ←[35m2014-05-24T13:41:56.053479+00:00
>     > heroku[run.2775]:←[0m Process exited with status 129
>     > ←[36m2014-05-24T13:43:44.649471+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed
>     > from cras hed to starting ←[36m2014-05-24T13:43:47.654203+00:00
>     > app[web.1]:←[0m RTD2: Running. ←[36m2014-05-24T13:43:46.357298+00:00
>     > heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with c ommand `node rtd2.js`
>     > ←[36m2014-05-24T13:44:32.992131+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
>     > ←[36m2014-05-24T13:44:32.992136+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m # followers:404
>     > ←[36m2014-05-24T13:44:33.365530+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
>     > ←[36m2014-05-24T13:44:33.365535+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m SearchFollow:
>     > followed @Ch loixxHDM ←[36m2014-05-24T13:44:46.459802+00:00
>     > heroku[web.1]:←[0m Error R10 (Boot timeout ) -> Web process failed to
>     > bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
>     > ←[36m2014-05-24T13:44:46.459802+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Stopping
>     > process with S IGKILL ←[36m2014-05-24T13:44:47.883661+00:00
>     > heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from star ting to crashed
>     > ←[36m2014-05-24T13:44:47.862070+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process
>     > exited with sta tus 137 name@PEWTON ~/twit (master) $
```